# How can two operations be in if-else if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement

I am trying to do make a simple soccer simulation program but I have an issue on matching teams to each other. if statement quits the loop after finding one condition. But I want to do two condition and two operations. Is it possible?

```
package soccer.simulator;
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * @author Sertac
 */
public class SoccerSimulator {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int HomeTeamScore = 0;
        int AwayTeamScore = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        String HomeTeam = new String();
        String AwayTeam = new String();
        int HomeTeamID = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        int AwayTeamID = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

        if(HomeTeamID == AwayTeamID){
            while (HomeTeamID != AwayTeamID){
                AwayTeamID = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
            }
        }

        if(HomeTeamID == 0 || AwayTeamID == 0){
            if(HomeTeamID == 0){
                HomeTeam = "Arsenal";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Arsenal";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 1 || AwayTeamID == 1){
            if(HomeTeamID == 1){
                HomeTeam = "Barcelona";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Barcelona";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 2 || AwayTeamID == 2){
            if(HomeTeamID == 2){
                HomeTeam = "Bayern Munich";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Bayern Munich";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 3 || AwayTeamID == 3){
            if(HomeTeamID == 3){
                HomeTeam = "Chelsea";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Chelsea";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 4 || AwayTeamID == 4){
            if(HomeTeamID == 4){
                HomeTeam = "Borussia Dortmund";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Borussia Dortmund";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 5 || AwayTeamID == 5){
            if(HomeTeamID == 5){
                HomeTeam = "Galatasaray";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Galatasaray";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 6 || AwayTeamID == 6){
            if(HomeTeamID == 6){
                HomeTeam = "Juventus";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Juventus";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 7 || AwayTeamID == 7){
            if(HomeTeamID == 7){
                HomeTeam = "Manchester United";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Manchester United";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 8 || AwayTeamID == 8){
            if(HomeTeamID == 8){
                HomeTeam = "Milan";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Milan";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 9 || AwayTeamID == 9){
            if(HomeTeamID == 9){
                HomeTeam = "Real Madrid";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Real Madrid";
            }
        }

        //Generating each random integers in range 0..99 for 90 minutes
        for(int minutes = 0; minutes <= 90; minutes++){
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

            //if random int equals 0,1,2 home team scores
            if(randomInt < 3){ HomeTeamScore = HomeTeamScore + 1; }

            //if random int equals 98,99 away team scores
            //home team has 1 more int because playing at home is better
            if(randomInt > 97){ AwayTeamScore = AwayTeamScore + 1; }                         
        }
        System.out.println ("Simulation for match of the week:");
        System.out.println (HomeTeam + " " + HomeTeamScore + " - " + AwayTeamScore + " " + AwayTeam);

        }   
    }
```

And the output is:
`3 - 1 Arsenal`

or:
`Arsenal 2 - 1`

Comment: Please elaborate more on this.

Comment: The problem is I can't see two teams on output. Only one team appears on output, I need two teams for single match.

Comment: Please stick to Java naming conventions, variables are in lowerCamelCase. UpperCamelCase is reserved for classes. This code is basically unintelligible.

Comment: Change how your program works. Create a function that returns the name of the team based on the number, call it for each team.

Comment: The base cause is the `else`, if you match team 1 for home team, you won´t get to match team 3 for away team since it is in the `else` branch (which is not executed). Delete your `else` from `if (homeTeam ==1) | (awayTeam ==1) .... else`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only set one team name because there's no loop at all, only one final condition will be true in your huge `if-else` statement. An easier approach (and highly recommendable in order to keep the sanity for anyone else that will touch your code in the near future) would be storing your team names in an array.-

```
String[] teamNames = new String[] {"Arsenal", "Barcelona", "Bayern Munich", "Chelsea", "Borussia Dortmund", "Galatasaray", "Juventus", "Manchester United", "Milan", "Real Madrid"};
```

And then replacing the whole `if-else` for.-

```
HomeTeam = teamNames[HomeTeamID];
AwayTeam = teamNames[AwayTeamID];
```

---

As a side note, you should stick to java conventions for variable naming, and use lower case camelCase (`homeTeam`, `awayTeam`, `homeTeamID`, `awayTeamId`).

Answer (score 2):

changed `else if` to `if`

try

```
import java.util.Random;
/**
 * @author Sertac
 */
public class SoccerSimulator {
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int HomeTeamScore = 0;
        int AwayTeamScore = 0;
        Random randomGenerator = new Random();

        String HomeTeam = new String();
        String AwayTeam = new String();
        int HomeTeamID = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
        int AwayTeamID = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);

        if(HomeTeamID == AwayTeamID){
            while (HomeTeamID != AwayTeamID){
                AwayTeamID = randomGenerator.nextInt(10);
            }
        }

        if(HomeTeamID == 0 || AwayTeamID == 0){
            if(HomeTeamID == 0){
                HomeTeam = "Arsenal";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Arsenal";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 1 || AwayTeamID == 1){
            if(HomeTeamID == 1){
                HomeTeam = "Barcelona";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Barcelona";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 2 || AwayTeamID == 2){
            if(HomeTeamID == 2){
                HomeTeam = "Bayern Munich";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Bayern Munich";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 3 || AwayTeamID == 3){
            if(HomeTeamID == 3){
                HomeTeam = "Chelsea";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Chelsea";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 4 || AwayTeamID == 4){
            if(HomeTeamID == 4){
                HomeTeam = "Borussia Dortmund";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Borussia Dortmund";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 5 || AwayTeamID == 5){
            if(HomeTeamID == 5){
                HomeTeam = "Galatasaray";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Galatasaray";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 6 || AwayTeamID == 6){
            if(HomeTeamID == 6){
                HomeTeam = "Juventus";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Juventus";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 7 || AwayTeamID == 7){
            if(HomeTeamID == 7){
                HomeTeam = "Manchester United";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Manchester United";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 8 || AwayTeamID == 8){
            if(HomeTeamID == 8){
                HomeTeam = "Milan";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Milan";
            }
        }  if(HomeTeamID == 9 || AwayTeamID == 9){
            if(HomeTeamID == 9){
                HomeTeam = "Real Madrid";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Real Madrid";
            }
        }

        //Generating each random integers in range 0..99 for 90 minutes
        for(int minutes = 0; minutes <= 90; minutes++){
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);

            //if random int equals 0,1,2 home team scores
            if(randomInt < 3){ HomeTeamScore = HomeTeamScore + 1; }

            //if random int equals 98,99 away team scores
            //home team has 1 more int because playing at home is better
            if(randomInt > 97){ AwayTeamScore = AwayTeamScore + 1; }                         
        }
        System.out.println ("Simulation for match of the week:");
        System.out.println (HomeTeam + " " + HomeTeamScore + " - " + AwayTeamScore + " " + AwayTeam);

        }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
if(HomeTeamID == 0 || AwayTeamID == 0){
            if(HomeTeamID == 0){
                HomeTeam = "Arsenal";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Arsenal";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 1 || AwayTeamID == 1){
            if(HomeTeamID == 1){
                HomeTeam = "Barcelona";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Barcelona";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 2 || AwayTeamID == 2){
            if(HomeTeamID == 2){
                HomeTeam = "Bayern Munich";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Bayern Munich";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 3 || AwayTeamID == 3){
            if(HomeTeamID == 3){
                HomeTeam = "Chelsea";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Chelsea";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 4 || AwayTeamID == 4){
            if(HomeTeamID == 4){
                HomeTeam = "Borussia Dortmund";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Borussia Dortmund";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 5 || AwayTeamID == 5){
            if(HomeTeamID == 5){
                HomeTeam = "Galatasaray";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Galatasaray";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 6 || AwayTeamID == 6){
            if(HomeTeamID == 6){
                HomeTeam = "Juventus";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Juventus";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 7 || AwayTeamID == 7){
            if(HomeTeamID == 7){
                HomeTeam = "Manchester United";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Manchester United";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 8 || AwayTeamID == 8){
            if(HomeTeamID == 8){
                HomeTeam = "Milan";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Milan";
            }
        } else if(HomeTeamID == 9 || AwayTeamID == 9){
            if(HomeTeamID == 9){
                HomeTeam = "Real Madrid";
            }else{
                AwayTeam = "Real Madrid";
            }
        }
```

U are always assigning only one team, either home or away team since you are using a wrong construction here. Try something like:

```
switch(HomeTeamID)
{
case 0: HomeTeam = "Arsenal";
        break;
case 1: HomeTeam = "Barcelona";
...
break
}
```

and same for away team:

```
switch(HomeTeamID)
{
case 0: AwayTeam = "Arsenal";
        break;
case 1: AwayTeam = "Barcelona";
...
break
}
```

And you should check the java code conventions..The variable names should begin with a lowercase.

Answer (score 0):

Replace  else if with if, and code should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I would start from the very beginning. What is it that you are trying to do.

Given some teams you want to select two random teams to play each other, one home and one away.

Currently you are selecting two random `int` ids from a `Random` and using those to lookup teams in an implied array of teams.

So, first go with @ssantos' suggestion - make the array explicit and simply get the index from there.

But, we have an issue - a team cannot play itself. So in fact we need a slightly different approach. What you need to do is take the array of all teams, shuffle it, and then read pairs out of the array. This is in fact how selection tends to work in tournaments.

Here is my suggested code:

```
private static final String[] TEAM_NAMES = new String[]{"Arsenal", "Barcelona", "Bayern Munich", "Chelsea", "Borussia Dortmund", "Galatasaray", "Juventus", "Manchester United", "Milan", "Real Madrid"};
private static final Random RANDOM = new Random();

public static void main(final String args[]) {
    List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(TEAM_NAMES));
    while (teams.size() > 1) {
        teams = playRound(teams);
    }
    System.out.println("The champion is " + teams);
}

public static List<String> playRound(final List<String> teams) {
    Collections.shuffle(teams);
    final Iterator<String> teamsIter = teams.iterator();
    final List<String> winners = new ArrayList<>();
    while (teamsIter.hasNext()) {
        final String winner = play(teamsIter.next(), teamsIter.next());
        winners.add(winner);
    }
    return winners;
}

public static String play(final String team1, final String team2) {
    return RANDOM.nextBoolean() ? team1 : team2;
}
```

From the top:

First we declare out constants - the array of teams and the `Random` instance. These variables are `static final` so they are named in `BLOCK_CAPITALS`.

**main**

Next we have out `main` method. This method takes the teams and reads them into a `List`. We need to make a copy of the teams so that we don't mess around with the teams array. A `List` is a more flexible structure, as you'll see later. Also note that you need a power of two of teams - if teams play in pairs then you need a number divisible by two in each round.

The method now goes into a `while` loop. This structure keeps playing all the winning teams from each round against each other until an ultimate winner is reached - the tournament champion. It prints out the champion's name.

**playRound**

This is where the magic happens.

The method first `shuffles` incoming teams so that they are retrieved at random. It then gets the `Iterator` for the `List` - this allows you to walk along the `List` element by element. This is also where the error will be thrown if there isn't an even number of teams - the second `next()` will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

The method then goes into another `while` loop - while the `Iterator` isn't empty it calls `play` with two teams. It puts the winning teams into the `winners` `List`. This is the `List` that is returned in the end.

Not that a `List` has an `add` method so that you can fill it dynamically - this is different to an array which has a fixed size.

**play**

This is where your actual simulation would go. Currently it selects a winner at random - you could put your current method in.